# How to merge two data frames on common columns in R with sum of others using dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way using the "dplyr" package to intersect two data frames and sum one column.  For example:

Given DF 1

```
Var1  Var2  Var3
1     A     5
1     B     4
2     A     5
2     B     3
2     C     4
```

DF 2

```
Var1  Var2  Var3
1     A     3
1     D     2
2     E     3
2     B     3
2     G     2
```

And return
DF 3

```
Var1  Var2  Var3
1     A     8
2     B     6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how easy is that my friend?

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, key = c('var1', 'var2')) %>%
mutate(sum = var2 + var3)
```

Comment: should it not be an `inner_join` given he said intersect